# Aave V3 Liquidations - Testing on Sepolia

Tags: aave, sepolia

I'm trying to test my nodejs app on the Sepolia testnet. What I want to do is monitor some events, gather user accounts, I will then call getUserAccountData() from the pool to see the HF. As explained here: https://docs.aave.com/developers/guides/liquidations

However, when I check the test contracts on Etherscan: https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/v3-testnet-addresses , I don't see any logged events. Has anybody done something similar? It's Aave V3, that I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Which contract did you check? Please check this contract: [Pool-Proxy-Aave](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xE7EC1B0015eb2ADEedb1B7f9F1Ce82F9DAD6dF08)  so you can view the transactions and logs. I believe you may have checked the [Pool-Implementation](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x02c3e5420527d75c1c864a58d6a2a73b0efbfa4d) contract.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test liquidations

- [You can deploy Aave V3 protocol fully in an unit test suite, example here](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/aave_v3/_autosummary_aave_v3/eth_defi.aave_v3.deployer.html#module-eth_defi.aave_v3.deployer)
- Aave deployer comes with test faucets - you can create some pools for yourself to test
- Then you can easily manipulate pool balances, forward time and cause liquidation events to happen - [example unit tests here](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/master/tests/aave_v3/test_aave_v3_loan.py)